# Use angular brackets within single quotes with i18n play framework 2.4

Tags: java, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.4

I'm using the i18n Messaging of Playframework 2.4 java.
I've some messages in which I need to insert dynamic strings in runtime. Hence I've used placeholder strings for that surrounded with <> angular brackets
Following is how my messages.en file looks:

```
message.notification.eventOccured = '<PLACEHOLDER_STRING>' has occured. We''re sorry.
```

Now I read this message from my program with:

```
play.i18n.Messages.get("message.notification.eventOccured").replace("<PLACEHOLDER_STRING>", "Actual String");
```

My expected output is:

```
'Actual String' has occured. We're sorry.
```

But I'm getting:

```
'Actual String ' has occured. We're sorry.
```

There's a space character inserted just before the second single quote.

Why is this happening? Has it got something to do with angular brackets? Also if any workaround to get my desired output.

Thanks.

Comment: Curious. There is some regex parsing that goes on in [the source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/i18n/Messages.scala) but hard to tell immediately if there is an issue there or if that code is actually involved in your problem. Have you experimented with escape characters?